# Add Permission to Object

Tags: object, permissions

I have a System called 'A' that holds the objects of itself into data structure by name. Basically System 'A' has a function called getObject(obj_name). This function creates an object with the given name, obj_name, if it's not already exists and then return it otherwise it just return the object.

Now, Program 1 uses System 'A' and creates an object called "Program1_Object" using above function (getObject)

Program 2 calls getObject with "Program1_Object" as its argument.

The problem in here is getObject returns Program 1 object to Program 2. I want to add permission to that object that if object is not meant for the caller program returns an error or create a new one for the caller program.

What is a trick behind it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` could be a simple wrapper for a hash table.  Permissions could be implemented with an additional parameter to `getObject` stating the permissions of the calling code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there anyway that getObject can automatically creates a permission instead of passing permission to getObject function?

Comment: @markfw -- if you want to create a meaningful permission system, then you need to get extra information from the caller.  If you don't want to pass that information as a parameter, then you need to get it some other way, perhaps by pulling it from the meta-information of the program.  How you do that depends what language you're using -- in Perl, for example, I believe there's a way for a function to determine what code called it.

Comment: For languages such as C or C++ I have to create a program that grabs the meta data from caller function and use it as a key, am I right?